# "object3d.quaternion.set(q)" doesn't work?

Tags: three.js

I have a quaternion that I want to ".set", not ".apply".  I could get the world quaternion and calculate what I need to ".apply" to get what I want, but isn't it reasonable that ".set" should work?

In this code, trying the "scene.quaternion.set()" causes the scene to vanish.

```
  "use strict";  
  let scene, camera, renderer, geometry, material, mesh, quaternion;
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, 800/600, 0.1, 10 );
  camera.position.z = 5;
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( 800, 600 );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1);
  material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { wireframe:true } );
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( mesh );
  quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(0, .6, 0, .8);
// the following statement causes the scene to vanish:
//  scene.quaternion.set(quaternion);
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

EDIT: (comments for answerer)
From the quaternion docs:

> .copy ( q : Quaternion ) : Quaternion
> Copies the x, y, z and w properties of q into this quaternion.
>
> .set ( x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, w : Float ) : Quaternion
> Sets x, y, z, w properties of this quaternion.

I can't argue with an answer that works, but somehow this wording would never have gotten me to try ".copy" over ".set".  THANKS!

EDIT 2 (after reflection)
I see I mis-used ".set".  The folllowing also works:

```
  scene.quaternion.set(0,.6,0,.8);
```

Comment: Not an expert on quaternions but I think its just a nomenclature confusion. I understand `set` as in _set the property_. Remember that quaternions represents the axis about which a rotation will occur. They don't  represent a final rotation. Therefore `apply` is needed to _apply the properties previously set_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> scene.quaternion.set(quaternion);

The signature of [Quaternion.set()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=quat#api/en/math/Quaternion.set) is:

```
set(x: number, y: number, z: number, w: number): Quaternion;
```

So you can't apply an instance of `Quaternion`. Try it with `copy()` instead:

```js
scene.quaternion.copy(quaternion);
```